# React useState(prevState => ...) not working when a listener callback updates state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

### Introduction

I have a progress time bar on my screen which is advanced in a useEffect, inside a setInterval. The problem comes when my DB listener is triggered and executes its callback, where the code updates other states.

### Code

```
const [isRoomFull, setIsRoomFull] = useState(false);
const [timerProgress, setTimerProgress] = useState(0);

 ...
const startGame = () => {
   ...
   advanceTimer();
}

const listenRoomChanges = (roomDoc) => {
   const { full } = roomDoc.data();

   setIsRoomFull(full);
};

const advanceTimer = () => {
  setTimerProgress(timerProgress + 1 / GAME_DURATION);
};

useEffect(() => {
    if (roomId) {
      const { firebase } = props;

      roomListener.current = firebase
        .getDatabase()
        .collection("rooms")
        .doc(roomId)
        .onSnapshot(listenRoomChanges); // <- DB listener callback
    }

    return () => {
      detachListener();
    };
  }, [roomId]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (timerProgress > 0 && timerProgress < 1) {
    // Advance the timer every second
    var timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
      advanceTimer();
    }, 1000);
  }

  return () => {
    clearInterval(timerInterval);
  };
}, [timerProgress]);
```

### Problem

The problem is that the timerProgress value is reset every time the listener callback is executed.

For example, if I do a console.log(timerProgress) inside the listener callback

```
const listenRoomChanges = (roomDoc) => {
   const { full } = roomDoc.data();
   console.log(timerProgress); // <----
   setIsRoomFull(full);
};
```

it will show me 0, when the real value is 10 secs, for example.

### My current workaround

If when updating the timer progress I do

```
  const advanceTimer = () => {
    setTimerProgress(
      (prevTimerProgress) => prevTimerProgress + 1 / GAME_DURATION
    );
  };
```

instead, the timerProgress will not be "reset" to 0 when the DB listener callback updates other states...

But for some reason, this is not working 100% well (when the DB listener callback updates other states, the timerProgress advances *nStateUpdatesInTheDbListenerCallback* times faster, I don't know the reason but this is happening).

Does someone know how to solve this problem? Any special hook for this? Why is this happening?

I think that I can use useRef() but this will not fire a re-render...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove** `return () => { clearInterval(time interval);};`

From

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (timerProgress > 0 && timerProgress < 1) {
    // Advance the timer every second
    var timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
      advanceTimer();
    }, 1000);
  }

  return () => {
    clearInterval(timerInterval);
  };
}, [timerProgress]);
```

And let me know,

Comment: Didn't work. The timeInterval is recreated again and again when timerProgress change. That is why I clear it. If I do this, the time interval is buggy, increasing and decreasing.

Comment: Okay, just remove timerProgress from `useEffect(() => {
  if (timerProgress > 0 && timerProgress < 1) {
    // Advance the timer every second
    var timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
      advanceTimer();
    }, 1000);
  }

  return () => {
    clearInterval(timerInterval);
  };
}, []);`

Comment: You want to give an empty array as second argument to useEffect so that the function is only run once after the initial render.

Because of how closures work, this will make the counter variable always reference the initial value. You can use the function version of setTimerProgress instead to always get the correct value.

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setTimerProgress((prevTimerProgress) => prevTimerProgress + 1 / GAME_DURATION)
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);`